# Надежная изоляция без копирования бинарника Python или отмена эффектов site.py

Tags: python, инициализация, virtualenv, интерпретатор

Читаю [PEP 0405](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/) и вижу вот такую фразу:

> Tools such as rvirtualenv, which do not copy the Python binary into the virtual environment, cannot provide reliable isolation from system site directories.

Весь гугль измучал, рассылки почитал, но но не могу найти почему cannot provide.

Казалось бы, для надежной изоляции, должно быть достаточно:

- вернуть в ванильное состояние переменных в `sys`; в частности, в `sys.path` восстановить из `Py_GetPath` и вычистить `sys.modules` от всего, что теперь не в нем;
- проверить целостность `__import__`, в случае чего, восстановив через `builtin___import__` (или `PyImport_ImportModuleLevel`);
- пробежать по `sys.modules`, проверив их нетронутость, а если что-то нарушено — нещадно перегрузить. Или даже просто перегрузить, не заморачиваясь каким-то анализом — простое друг надежного.

Да, действия не самые тривиальные, но как-то не верится, что нельзя привести интерпретатор к ванильному состоянию, нейтрализовав эффекты `site`/`sitecustomize`/`usercustomize`. Все же есть под капотом, libpython все что нужно экспортирует, бери да переинициализируй интерпретатор. (Да, это повышает время запуска, я знаю, спасибо, временно проигнорируем этот аспект.)

Что я упускаю из вида?

Comment: virtualenv сделан как раз чтобы избежать такой пляски. Мало ли что подразумевается под "reliable isolation", как говорится, работает - не трожь.

Comment: - Насчет вопроса *(почему `cannot provide`)* - в том же самом `PEP 0405` сказано, что:

> Virtualenv must copy the binary in order to provide isolation, as Python dereferences a symlinked executable before searching for `sys.prefix.`

- То есть, как я понимаю (не особо сильно пока вдавался в вопрос), внутреннее поведение бинарника питона каким-то образом мешает подходу с `symlink'ами`, а, поскольку `rvirtualenv` реализует виртуализацию `environment'a` с их помощью, то и получается `unreliable isolation` для некоторых кейсов.

Comment: Могу капитально заблуждаться, вопрос крутой и надо почитать :)

Comment: Насчет «работает — не трожь»: На самом деле я хочу изоляцию без virtualenv и pip, на манер Ruby'шного Bundler'а. Без симлинков, с единой (на окружение) коллекцией версионированных egg'ов. Чем-то, по сути, как оно было раньше во времена еще setuptools, с `pkg_resources.require()`.

И выясняю какие подводные камни разрушения изоляции меня ждут. Хочу понять, почему все пошли в сторону (субъективно неудобных) pip+virtualenv.

Comment: ответ на заголовок вопроса: `python -S` и/или `python -I`. Про содержимое: как `virtualenv` (нет `r` спереди) так и `python3 -mvenv` предоставляют изоляцию по умолчанию (и наоборот с `--system-site-packages` опцией). По описанию http://www.buildout.org/ может подойти, хотя `pip + wheel` в современных версиях могут быть более предпочтительны.

Answer (score 1):

Одна из проблем решений типа RVirtualEnv заключается в не всегда корректной работе с директорией site packages.

Пример кода:

```
import sys
import os
import site

if __name__ == '__main__':
    site_packages_dir = site.getsitepackages()[0]
    site_pth_file = os.path.join(
        site_packages_dir, 'something_new.pth'
    )
    project_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    with open(site_pth_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(project_root)
        f.close()
```

Comment: Код добавляет `project_root` в `sys.path` глобально для всех скриптов, что не хорошо. Что приведённый пример должен был продемонстрировать?  Кстати,  `f.close()` бесполезен внутри `with`-конструкции.